# Vuejs doesn't see localStorage item on login until I reload the page

Tags: vue.js

I have a sample vue app where I'm trying to add authentication.

The backend for this app returns a jwt string on successful login.

The problem is that the projects are not fetched after login.

But if I refresh the page manually, the projects list is loaded without any errors

**login**

```
submit () {
  api.login(this.cred).then((res) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token)
    this.$router.push('/projects')
  })
}
```

**projects** view has the following part

```
  mounted () {
    this.fetchProjects()
  }
```

**error**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/projects/ 401 (Unauthorized)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401(…)
```

**up** (projects api)

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer: ' + window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')
  }
}

export default {
  fetchProjects: () => {
    return axios.get(Projects, config)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing something similar to: this.access_token = window.localStorage.get('access_token')? If yes, when you login you have to update that variable, otherwise it will be null until you run that code again.

Comment: updated my question with some code from projects api. Do you think it's incorrect?

Comment: It sounds like your router going to the projects page is not causing your localStorage item to be read, but a page-load on the projects page does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a function return headers, like this:

```
function getHeaders() {
   return {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer: ' + 
     window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')
   }  
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I did. I posted an answer but then decided to delete it :)

Answer (score 0):

After you set the the localStorage you need update that `config.headers.Authorization`. Otherwise it will have effect only when you refresh the page.